# SharePoint Timer Job Stopped working after Password Change

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointfoundation2010, sharepoint-timer-job

The Password of my SharePoint Development Server has been changed, the Timer Job has stopped working Although when I put the Debugger on the Base Constructor, it Fires only on the Base Constructor only and the Other Constructor & Execute method are not coming to Fire on Debug Mode.

I have changed the Password in All the Application Pools through IIS, I have reset the IIS, Stopped & started the Timer Service as described in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204897/changing-password-of-farm-account-from-central-adminstration) but nothing solved my issue.

I have also Restarted the Server but still the Timer Job is not getting Execute.

I am a bit new in SharePoint, your precious help is Required

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 things I would do here:

Option 1

1. Go to Central Admin
2. Click on "monitoriing"
3. Click on "timer Jobs"
4. Restart and set all jobs which are supposed to run to the right option, Start, Set, Automatic etc

Option 2

1. Stop all timer jobs
2. User Powershell Scripts to restart, I found this link for you: https://petri.com/manage-timer-jobs-sharepoint-2013-with-powershell

Option 3

1. check the current service state in the system control / services menu. If the service is disabled, then please enable it. If it's really not running, please start the service manually.
2. If it already runs, you have possibly started the installer task without appropriate permissions to request the current state of the service.

Most importantly...
**Run all commands as Administrator or Site Owner with permissions checked***